# Bak File Backup Restore Docker Azure SQL Edge in M1 Apple

Tags: sql-server, azure, docker, apple-m1

I try to restore a .bak file Azure Sql Edge container with Azure Data Studio. I have Apple M1 chipset. I am using docker for mssql:

```
mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge   latest    5dba915af82f   8 weeks ago   1.83GB
```

I need to install Mssql and restore a database with .bak file. But I get below error:

```
Restore FilelistOnly from disk = N'/var/opt/mssql/backup/test.bak'
Restore Database test From disk = N'/var/opt/mssql/backup/test.bak' WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY, MOVE 'test_data' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/test.mdf', MOVE 'test_Log' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/test.ldf'
```

> Msg 12824, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 The sp_configure value
> 'contained database authentication' must be set to 1 in order to
> restore a contained database.  You may need to use RECONFIGURE to set
> the value_in_use.

I try to

```
sp_configure 'contained database authentication', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

I am getting:

> Msg 15392, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_configure, Line 166 The
> specified option 'contained database authentication' is not supported
> by this edition of SQL Server and cannot be changed using
> sp_configure.

How to restore my backup on azure sql edge?

Answer (score 3):

You're running Azure SQL Edge, which is a special edition intended for IoT scenarios.

Per the docs

> Additionally, a database created on Microsoft SQL Server or Azure SQL
> can be restored on Azure SQL Edge, provided the database does not
> contain any of the features not supported by Azure SQL Edge.

[Backup and Restore - Azure SQL Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql-edge/backup-restore)

And [Contained Databases are not supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql-edge/features#unsupported-features) in Azure SQL Edge.

So either start with a backup of a non-contained database, or use one of the "regular" [SQL Server Editions on Docker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-docker-container-deployment).

Answer (score 0):

Regular SQL docker editions for M1 Apple Silicon is still not supported. Azure SQL Edge not usefull for this activity. So can not import bak or bacpac files to local sql via M1 macs!

Answer (score 0):

Is perfectly possible to do so.

Copy the .bak file to the Docker Container (You’ll only need to do this step if your .bak file is located outside the Docker container).

1. create a folder inside the Docker container:
   sudo docker exec -it [server name] mkdir /var/opt/mssql/backup
2. Now copy the database .bak file into that folder:
   sudo docker cp [db name].bak sql_server_demo:/var/opt/mssql/backup

Now install Azure data studio and connect to the SQL Edge server.

Use the restore option in Azure data studio to restore the BAK.

[Screenshot of restore option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMM5q.png)

This is a quick way to import a bak file to your SQL Edge edition.